# How can a more efficient volatility estimator be used to improve the co-variance matrix?

Tags: standard-deviation, covariance, covariance-matrix

Using mean-variance, I estimate a co-variance matrix $\Sigma$ to obtain the best weights in my portfolio.

However, there are other ways to compute the volatility $\sigma$ than historical standard deviation, for instance using Yang and Zhang estimator.

I don't understand however the link between the vol. estimation and the co-variance matrix. I know that on the diagonals you'll find the volatility, but how do you re-calculate the co-variance matrix after you have obtained more efficient volatility estimates?

Comment: A rough answer: If you know by which sum of squares of one variable you can estimate the variance/volatility, the covariance is a sum of products of two variables. See  https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/27741/understanding-yang-zhang-volatility-estimator and the formula for $\sigma^2_{rs}$.